# Accepting Input from Command Line in C

Tags: c, user-input, scanf

How do I use `scanf()` IN C to accept multiple inputs from the command line? I'm trying to get a name, followed by an arbitrary number of values from a user, on the same line. I know the `scanf()` function is space/new line delimited.

For example the user enters:
dog 2 5 1

I know `scanf()` will read the "dog", but how do I get it to read the following values. I can't use `scanf("%s, %d, %d, %d", a, b, c, d)` because there could be more than, or less than 3 values entered.

Comment: Do you know at any time during input how many values will be entered?

Comment: One simple option is just to attempt to read the max number of inputs and check the return value of `scanf` to see how many inputs were read. Works well if the max number is known and fixed to a small value. Otherwise just keep calling `scanf("%d", &num)` in a loop until it fails to match. Depending on your full requirements there may be better options (e.g. use something other than `scanf`).

Answer (score 1):

You could pass arguments to the main function itself. The prototype for main is

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

You could use this to read the command line arguments. 
argc gives the total number of arguments (separated by a space), and argv is a vector that holds it.

For example user will enter: `./yourExecutable dog 2 5 1`
In this case the number of arguments would be 5 (including the name of your executable) and `argv[0]` would be your executable, argv[1] would be your `"dog"` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole line to a string buffer using `fgets()`.

Then split by spaces using `strtok()`.